# Webdriverjs can't update text in div wrapped paragraph

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation where I'd like to be able to update some default text in a `<p>` tag wrapped inside of a `<div>` tag but so far I have been unable to find a good solution for accomplishing this.

Here's a snippet of the HTML that I'd like to edit:

```
<div class="edit-text">
 <p> Default text </p>
</div>
```

I would like to reach in to the `<p>` tag and clear the text and/or update the text with something different.

I have tried a few different ways of editing the text, including finding the element and interacting with it:

```
var edit = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='edit-text']/p")))
edit.click()
edit.clear()
edit.sendKeys('Hello')
```

But this doesn't ever seem to work.  Is there something else that's going on that I'm failing to see?

I've seen a few other posts uses `executeScript` but I can't find a good way to use that approach and update the text the with the elements that this HTML uses because the browser doesn't seem to support finding elements by xpath.

Comment: I just dont understand why you are doing that? and how you do same thing via browser. For me it would make more sense if you will use innerHTML but not a send keys

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat It really just comes down to that fact that I don't really know what I'm doing :)  All I want to do is update the text, I just don't know the best approach.  How would you do it with innerHTML?

Comment: I am afraid that executeScript  is only option for you. But i still dont understand why you are doing that, what is you use case that you need to update it?

Comment: The paragraph is one of those rich text editor features but it is hard to work that into the original question without adding too much detail.  I'm fine with using executeScript, just not sure how to get it to work with xpath.  Thanks for the help and feedback.

Comment: You must use css selectors to get it work but its pretty simple div.class-text>p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting a little bit I was able to get the solution by using `executeScript` and `document.querySelector` to locate the css.

```
document.querySelector(".edit-text").innerHTML = "Hello world"
```